# How can I check if a file is being downloaded?

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi which I want to use to automate downloads to a network drive.  I would like to restart the machine on a regular basis using `cron` (I've heard they're not the most stable of things) but obviously, I would prefer not to restart it half way through an incomplete download.

I'll probably be downloading using several different methods but one of the ways I'll be using soon is [get_iplayer](http://linuxcentre.net/getiplayer) and probably basic `wget` stuff too.

Is there a way I can check if one is in progress?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Could you add information about the download process you are implementing?

Comment: I've added a bit more info.

Comment: If your system is unstable, find out why. To me Linux generally has been _rock solid_. Reasons of instability include hardware problems (RAM, CPU fan not working leads to overheating, machine is sensible to voltage fluctuations, network/other cables near electromagnetic interference sources like fluorescent lights of electric motors) or software glitches (trouble with the driver of some card), and sometimes miscreants beating on the system (like the infamous SSH brute force login testers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some dirty ideas :

- Poll running software using ps : if a wget instance is running, then
  do not reboot.
- Create a lock file when triggering a download, and
  poll the lock file

Anyway, wget -c allow to continue an interrupted download.

Comment: I second the lock file idea.  Basically, just touch a file in `/tmp` or something right before calling `wget`, and delete that file after the wget call.  If this file exists, don't reboot.